# Zabbix API склеить вывод двух json запросов

Tags: json, api, zabbix

Всем привет. Есть 2 запроса json - host.get и hostgroup.get. Первый возвращает список хостов, второй список групп. В выводе второго запроса есть groupids, по которому можно отфильтровать хосты из первого запроса.

Первый запрос:

`curl -k -X POST https://zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d '{ "jsonrpc": "2.0","method": "host.get","params": { "output": ["host"], "groupids": ["200", "201"] }, "auth": "<TOKEN>","id": 1 }' | jq`

Вывод первого запроса:

`{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": [ { "hostid": "100", "host": "host1" }, { "hostid": "101", "host": "host2" } ], "id": 1 }`

host1 в группе 200, host2 в группе 201, но по выводу это не понятно.

Второй запрос:

`curl -k -X POST https://zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d '{ "jsonrpc": "2.0","method": "hostgroup.get","params": { "output": ["name"], "groupids": ["200", "201"]}, "auth": "<TOKEN>","id": 1 }' | jq`

Вывод второго запроса:

`{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": [ { "groupid": "200", "name": "Тест/Тест1" }, { "groupid": "201", "name": "Тест/Тест2" } ], "id": 1 }`

Как склеить вывод двух запросов (желательно через bash или python), чтобы получилось что-то вроде:

`{ "jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": [ { "hostid": "100", "host": "host1" "groupid": "200", "name": "Тест/Тест1" }, { "hostid": "101", "host": "host2" "groupid": "201", "name": "Тест/Тест2" } ], "id": 1 }`

Склеенный вывод не обязательно в формате json, главное чтобы было понятно, к какой группе относится каждый хост. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В host.get присутствует параметр selectHostGroups (или deprecated selectGroups), который и решил данную проблему.

`curl -k -X POST https://zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d '{ "jsonrpc": "2.0","method": "host.get","params": { "output": ["host"], "selectHostGroups": "extend", "groupids": ["200", "201"] }, "auth": "<TOKEN>","id": 1 }' | jq`